# Blur event not working on custom multi-select Vue component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Blur event is not working properly. It works if I click anywhere in the component except when clicking in the input field. If I click in the input field then outside the component, it won't trigger the blur event which closes the options list. How can I make the blur event on the outer div work after clicking on the input field and then clicking outside the component (* blur event should that be triggered if I click on the components list since it is still within the component, therefore I can't just place a blur event on the input field)

```
    <template>
  <div class="flex flex-col relative w-full">
    <span v-if="label" class="font-jost-medium mb-2">{{ label }}</span>
    <div>
      <div @blur="showOptions = false" :tabindex="tabIndex">
        <div
          class="border border-[#EAEAEA] bg-white rounded-md flex flex-col w-full"
        >
          <div
            v-if="selectedOptions.length"
            class="flex flex-wrap px-4 py-2 border-b gap-2"
          >
            <div
              v-for="option in selectedOptions"
              class="border bg-secondary rounded-full py-1 px-2 flex items-center"
            >
              <span>{{ option.text }}</span>
              <vue-feather
                type="x"
                class="h-3 w-3 ml-1.5 cursor-pointer"
                @click="onDeleteOption(option)"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="flex flex-row justify-end items-center px-4 cursor-pointer"
            :class="selectedOptions.length ? 'py-2' : 'p-4'"
            @click="showOptions = !showOptions"
          >
            <MagnifyingGlassIcon class="h-5 w-5 mr-2" />
            <input
              class="focus:outline-0 w-full"
              type="text"
              v-model="searchInput"
            />
            <vue-feather type="chevron-down" class="h-5 w-5" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div v-if="showOptions && optionsMap.length" class="options-list">
          <ul role="listbox" class="w-full overflow-auto">
            <li
              class="hover:bg-primary-light px-4 py-2 rounded-md cursor-pointer"
              role="option"
              v-for="option in optionsMap"
              @mousedown="onOptionClick(option)"
            >
              {{ option.text }}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div
          id="not-found"
          class="absolute w-full italic text-center text-inactive-grey"
          v-else-if="!optionsMap.length"
        >
          No records found
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, PropType, ref, watch } from "vue";
import { IconNameTypes } from "@/types/enums/IconNameTypes";
import { AppIcon } from "@/components/base/index";
import { MagnifyingGlassIcon } from "@heroicons/vue/24/outline";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "AppAutocomplete",
  components: {
    AppIcon,
    MagnifyingGlassIcon,
  },
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    tabIndex: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    options: {
      type: Array as PropType<{ text: string; value: string }[]>,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const showOptions = ref(false);

    const optionsMap = ref(props.options);
    const selectedOptions = ref<{ text: string; value: string }[]>([]);
    const searchInput = ref("");
    watch(searchInput, () => {
      optionsMap.value = props.options.filter((option1) => {
        return (
          !selectedOptions.value.some((option2) => {
            return option1.text === option2.text;
          }) &&
          option1.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.value.toLowerCase())
        );
      });
      sortOptionsMapList();
    });

    const onOptionClick = (option: { text: string; value: string }) => {
      searchInput.value = "";
      selectedOptions.value.push(option);
      optionsMap.value = optionsMap.value.filter((option1) => {
        return !selectedOptions.value.some((option2) => {
          return option1.text === option2.text;
        });
      });
      sortOptionsMapList();
      emit("update:modelValue", option.value);
    };

    const onDeleteOption = (option: { text: string; value: string }) => {
      selectedOptions.value = selectedOptions.value.filter((option2) => {
        return option2.text !== option.text;
      });
      optionsMap.value.push(option);
      sortOptionsMapList();
    };

    const sortOptionsMapList = () => {
      optionsMap.value.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);
      });
    };
    sortOptionsMapList();

    document.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(document.activeElement);
    });

    return {
      showOptions,
      optionsMap,
      searchInput,
      selectedOptions,
      IconNameTypes,
      onOptionClick,
      onDeleteOption,
    };
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.options-list,
#not-found {
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgb(19 19 28 / 12%);

  @apply border border-[#EAEAEA] rounded-md p-4 mt-1 absolute bg-white z-10 w-full;
}
ul {
  @apply max-h-52 #{!important};
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

[blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) is not an event that 'bubbles up' to outer elements, so it never reaches the parent div.  What you want is [focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event)

```html
<div @focusout="showOptions = false" :tabindex="tabIndex">
```

Comment: Both of these suggestions work however they close the list of options in the dropdown once selected. My idea with this autocomplete component is that when the user clicks on the input field to enter a search, a list with suggestions containing the word the user is typing will show under the input field. However when I use blur on input or focusout, it hides the list. i would like for the list to persist since user could select multiple options, until user clicks outside of the component.

Comment: none of blur, nor focusout work for me.. can the reason be, i use two named slots? what can i do ?